# Data 01 dia do mês retorna como último

Tags: javascript, html

Quando eu insiro o dia 01 como data, ele me retorna o último dia do mês anterior. Qual o motivo?

```js
 function myFunction() {
  var fromdate = new Date(document.getElementById('data_venc').value);
  alert(fromdate);
        var dd = fromdate.getDate();
        var mm = fromdate.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = fromdate.getFullYear();
  alert(dd + " " + mm);
        if(dd < 10)
        {
            dd = '0'+ dd;
   alert(dd);
        }
        if(mm < 10)
        {
            mm = '0' + mm;
   alert(mm);
        }
       //alert(newdate1);
 }
```

```html
<html>
 </head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="recuperar_usuario_senha">
   <form>
    <h2> Digite a data de vencimento: </h2>
    <input type="date" name="data_venc" id="data_venc"/>
    <h2>Informações Adicionais</h2>
    <textarea cols="45" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea" maxlength="225"></textarea>
    </br><input onClick="myFunction()" type="image" src="img/gera_boleto.png" value="Confirmar" id="gera_boleto">
   </form>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Isto acontece porque o javascript está convertendo a data para o fuso horário atual. Veja que o final do primeiro `alert` termina com `GMT-0300`:

```
Wed Dec 31 2014 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

Ou seja, o calculo realizado é `01/01/2015 - 3h`.

Para solucionar esse problema, utilize o método [toGMTString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString):

```
var input = document.getElementById('date').valueAsDate;
console.log(input.toGMTString()); // Thu, 01 Jan 2015 00:00:00 GMT
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu não encontrei referência para esse bug, mas aparentemente esta efetuando uma subtração, pois o formato passado é AAAA-MM-DD, concatenando com uma string `" "` a data é convertida corretamente.

Você pode usar o `toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")` para formatar no padrão brasileiro de `DD/MM/AAAA` conforme exemplo abaixo.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fromdate = new Date(document.getElementById('data_venc').value + " ");
  alert(fromdate);
  var dd = fromdate.getDate();
  var mm = fromdate.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = fromdate.getFullYear();
  alert(dd + " " + mm);
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
    alert(dd);
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
    alert(mm);
  }
  var r = fromdate.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")
  alert(r);
}
```

```html
<html>
</head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="recuperar_usuario_senha">
    <form>
      <h2> Digite a data de vencimento: </h2>
      <input type="date" name="data_venc" id="data_venc" />
      <h2>Informações Adicionais</h2>
      <textarea cols="45" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea" maxlength="225"></textarea>
      </br>
      <input onClick="myFunction()" type="image" src="img/gera_boleto.png" value="Confirmar" id="gera_boleto">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei alterando um pouco o projeto. As duas respostas funcionaram perfeitamente, mas como preciso comparar duas datas, acabei alterando um pouco o projeto e utilizando as datas no formato original. Para resolver isso, adicionei um dia na data antes da conversão para segundos. Segue o código:

```js
function myFunction() {
   var valorBoleto = document.getElementById('valor').value; // joga o valor na variavel valorBoleto
   var dataBoletoString = document.getElementById('data_venc').value; // joga a data na variavel dataBoletoString
   var dataBoleto = new Date(dataBoletoString);
   dataBoleto.setDate(dataBoleto.getDate() + 1);
   var dataBoletoSegundos = dataBoleto.getTime();
   var dataHoje = new Date();
   var dataHojeSegundos = dataHoje.getTime();
   if (valorBoleto <= 0){
    alert("Valor inválido! Insira o valor do boleto.");
   }else{
    var res = window.confirm("O valor do boleto é: R$ "+ valorBoleto + ". Está correto?");
    if (res == true){
     if(dataBoletoSegundos >= dataHojeSegundos){
      var dataCorreta = confirm("O vencimento deste boleto é dia: "+ dataBoleto.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR") + " , está correto?")
      if(dataCorreta == true){
       location.href="escolher_estab.php";
       window.open("boleto_manual.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbar=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=500, height=400");
      }
     }else{
      alert("O sistema não aceita datas anteriores ao dia de hoje.");
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

```html
<body oncontextmenu='return false' onselectstart='return false' ondragstart='return false'>  <!-- Não deixa o usuário clicar com o botão direito na página -->
  <div class="container clearfix">
   <?php
    include "header.php";
   ?>
   <div class="recuperar_usuario_senha">
    <form method="post" action="?acao=confirmar">
     <h1>Enviar boleto <em>SICLOP</em></h1>
     <h2> para <?php echo $nome_estab?></h2>
     <input type="password" name="estab" id="estab" value="<?php echo $nome_estab ?>" style="display:none"/> <!-- Nome do estabelecimento invisível para o usuário, para podermos pegar depois na ação GET -->
     <h2>Digite o valor do boleto:</h2>
     <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor"/>
     <h2> Digite a data de vencimento: </h2>
     <input type="date" name="data_venc" id="data_venc"/>
     <h2>Informações Adicionais</h2>
     <textarea cols="45" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea" maxlength="225"></textarea>
     </br><input onClick="myFunction()" type="image" src="img/gera_boleto.png" value="Confirmar" id="gera_boleto">
    </form>
   </div>
   <?php
    include "footer.php";
   ?>
  </div>
  </body>
```